# facebook app in python showing file list

Tags: python, django, facebook

i am making a facebook app in python with django. now i have successfully resolved the callback url to my localhost account. but the app is not displaying on facebook.

when i navigate to apps.facebook.com/'myappname', it authenticates and then displays the file list on project folder?

Comment: Can you clarify what's going on?

Comment: now it is showing an error: 

The URL http://192.168.2.2:8000/fbsample/?auth_token=53f2f9ba5ee21bc859bb7b41cece4f2d is not valid.

Please try again later. We appreciate your patience as the developers of roadies and Facebook resolve this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comments, I think I see what's going on.  192.168.2.2 is not a valid URL.  That is a local network IP, and cannot be accessed from outside your network.

You need to set your Canvas Callback URL to the external IP address of your modem.